# How to solve this system of 3 equations with substitution?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have the system:

$$-4 + λ = -3a + at\\ 1+2λ = -a + at\\ 3λ = 3a-at$$

but whenever I try to substitute, I end up getting lots of fractions that are hard to work with. By summing the 2nd and 3rd equations I get:

$$a = \frac{1+5\lambda}{2}$$

But then it's hard to work with it, no mtter where I substitute. Should it be like this or I'm doing something wrong?

PS: I can't use any theorem about determinants...

Comment: Note that $-4+\lambda=-3a+at=-(3a-at)=-3\lambda.$ Thus you can get the value of $\lambda$ easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this as the linear system
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-3 & 1 & -1\\
-1 & 1 & -2\\
3 & -1 & -3
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
a\\
at\\
\lambda
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
-4\\
1\\
0
\end{array}\right]
$$
which has solution
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
a\\
at\\
\lambda
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
3\\
6\\
1
\end{array}\right].
$$
That is, $a=3$, $t=2$, and $\lambda=1$.

Comment: This does not seem to meet the requirement to use the substitution method. But it certainly works well otherwise!